# Python idle closes when shell closes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I downloaded python 3 on a new computer and have gotten it to work. Unfortunately it now exits out of the idle window whenever I close the shell. I find this to be deeply annoying since it means I have to reopen the idle window after every single time I test the program. Is there any easy way to make the idle window stay?

Also I looked this up and mainly got irrelevant answers about the terminal/command line.

Comment: IDLE is annoying... I recommend using another IDE, such as PyCharm.

Comment: How do you start idle exactly?

Comment: I use windows 8 and I start idle by right clicking on the file and choosing the option "open with idle".